# How call a screen fuction clicking tabbar button. React navigation v5, setOption. React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

i just migrate from react navigation 4 to 5.
With the v4 i did

```
this.props.navigation.setParams({
      scrollToTop: this._scrollToTop,
    });
```

inside the Screen and call the function inside my custom MyTabBar like this:

```
onPress={() => {
              navigation.navigate("HomeStack");
              const navigationInRoute = state.routes[0].routes[0];
              navigationInRoute.params.scrollToTop();
}}
```

now with the v5 i must use setOption like documentations suggests:

```
this.props.navigation.setOptions({
      scrollToTop: this._scrollToTop,
    });
```

the problem is that i dont know how to call the function inside the tabbar.
This is my tabbar:

```
function MyTabBar({ state, descriptors, navigation }) {
  <View style={styles.FooterContenitor}>
          <TouchableHighlight>...          </TouchableHighlight>
          <TouchableHighlight>...          </TouchableHighlight>
          <TouchableHighlight 
            onPress={() => {
                  navigation.navigate("HomeStack");
                  ....how to call scrollToTop???....
            }}>...          
         </TouchableHighlight>
  </View>
}
```

Any help? Thanks

#### UPDATE #########################

this is my structure:

```
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
      <Tab.Navigator
        tabBar={props => <MyTabBar {...props} />}
        mode='modal'
        tabBarPosition="bottom"
        swipeEnabled={false}
        lazy={true}
        initialRouteName='HomeStack'//'HomeStack'
      >
        <Tab.Screen name="HomeStack" component={HomeStack}/>
        ...
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate();
```

if you are calling a component and use the navigation inside the component you have to pass navigation props to the component.
like

```
<Component navigation={this.props.navigation} />
```

then use `this.props.navigation.navigate();` inside component

Comment: I cant find scrollToTop inside navigation.  `navigation 
{jumpTo: ƒ, goBack: ƒ, navigate: ƒ, reset: ƒ, setParams: ƒ, …}
jumpTo: ƒ ()
goBack: ƒ ()
navigate: ƒ ()
reset: ƒ ()
setParams: ƒ ()
dispatch: ƒ dispatch(op)
emit: ƒ (_ref)
isFocused: ƒ ()
canGoBack: ƒ canGoBack()
__proto__: Object`

Comment: GoTo_top_function = () => {
    this.refs.ListView_Reference.scrollTo({animated: true}, 0);
  };

this is my function you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

I Solved using this inside my component:

```
this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().setOptions({
  scrollToTop: this._scrollToTop,
});
```

and calling the function:

```
onPress={() => {
    navigation.navigate("HomeStack"); 
    const indexTab = state.routes[state.index].state ? state.routes[state.index].state.index : null      
    if(state.index===0 && (indexTab===0 || !indexTab)){
        const key = state.routes[state.index].key
        descriptors[key].options.scrollToTop()
    }

}}
```